# Success of reading values from registry depends on if the application was built in IDE or from command line

Tags: msbuild, registry, c++builder

I'm facing a really strange problem.

I have an application built in *C++ Builder 2010*. This application reads and writes a bit to the registry. Since it's a *32-bit* application these keys end up in the *wow6432Node*. Every now and then it has appeared as though it has trouble reading the values from the registry. But only when build on the build server (using TeamCity) and never on the dev machines. Often a new commit and a rebuild would make the issue go away so it was hard to diagnose.

After some testing I noticed that I was able to reproduce it on the dev machine to. But only when building from the command line by calling *msbuild* manually. If the exact same project is built within the IDE there are no issues. But the exe produced when building from the command line, for some reason, can't read values from the registry.

There are no errors or warnings during builds. No files it can't find due to invalid paths or anything like that. Since msbuild is, as far as I can tell, used by the IDE when building to this has me scratching my head. I have tried to manually use different versions of msbuild etc, but nothing works.

So basically, on the same machine, my produced exe behaves differently depending on if I manually started the build from the command line or if the IDE started the build.

What on earth could this be?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your project setup or your environment, there is no way to diagnose this.  The first thing that comes to mind might be a UAC manifest conflict between the two builds.  Another thing to try is look at the IDE's message output windows to see the exact command-line parameters it is actually using to invoke msbuild, then use those same parameters in your command-line build and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Have your program record the Winapi error code when there is a failure to read the registry, it may give a clue

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The problem with this is that no error seems to occur. (At least no exception is thrown). Instead the call to _TRegistry->ReadString_ simply returns an empty string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I have gone over all the parameters once and found them to be identical. I could do it again to make sure. Regarding the possible UAC manifest conflict. How to I check/fix that? UAC for me has been limited to having to click on a button to allow things to run ass admin :)... The deep inner workings of it is something I haven't had to dig into before.

Comment: It may be something to do with the registry part of VirtualStore too.  Try running both your IDE and your commandline as administrator (if one of them is running as admin and one isn't, that would explain it)

Comment: perhaps the key you're looking for is actually stored in VirtualStore but not in the real registry.  You can [disable VirtualStore using the manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730053/how-to-disable-virtualstore-for-c-programs), this seems like a good idea to me (then you get errors when a registry operation fails, instead of silent awful behaviour)

Comment: as noted in that answer you'll also need to purge existing entries in the virtualstore to avoid lame behaviour (you can do this directly using RegEdit)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Update: Explicitly running the IDE as admin has no effect. The .exe compiled within the IDE is still always able to read the registry. (I forgot to rebuild). But the virtual store might still be the issue. I have tried forcing data to be written and read to the wow64 keys etc and nothing has worked. Is there any good text somewhere about creating a manifest file for C++ Builder 2010 projects so I make sure it's picked up and used correctly?

Comment: I linked in my earlier comment, IDK if there is anything more accurate

Comment: @inquam:  in CB2010, `TRegistry` has `LastError` and `LastErrorMsg` properties.  So when `ReadString()` returns a blank string, you can check the `LastError` to see whether it really was blank or a reading error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time trying to force the application to use specific registry views etc I was encouraged to look into the UAC manifest settings. I found that the application did in fact have a manifest file, named correctly and in the correct spot. It was also included in the *.cbproj* file and compiled by the resource compiler.

**But**, something got me thinking that perhaps it's not being used correctly. After some digging it seems like if *runtime themes* is enabled for the project that will create a "default" application manifest that will be used.

Disabling *runtime themes* will allow the compiler to actually use your custom application maniftest file (not exactly well documented, but I have found that to be the case with a lot of Embarcaderos things). By doing this I was able to set the required execution level for the application and things started to work just fine.

You can still manually enable the support for *runtime themes* in the maniftest file you create. You forms might look a bit strange in the ide since that will think that *runtime themes* are disabled.

To manually add *runtime theme* support you add the dependency to your custom application maniftest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

 ...

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  ...

</assembly>
```

Save it as *Foo.exe.manifest*, where *Foo.exe* is your application name.
You then create a *.rc* file for your application. For instance *FooManifest.rc*

```
#define MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID 1
#define RT_MANIFEST 24
MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "Foo.exe.manifest"
```

Now you will be able to build your application using your own custom application manifest and still maintain support for *runtime themes*.

Comment: Yes, in CB2010, there is no setting in the Project Options to use a custom manifest, you have to disable the default (themes-only) manifest and use an .rc/.res file to provide a custom manifest. The option to use a custom manifest was added to the Project Options in XE2.